# Why Boostrap layout doesn't display correctly with row inside container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap responsive less files. I have a layout like this:

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="contentwrap" class="row">
      <div id="content" class="span8">
        <!-- some content -->
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar" class="span4">
        <!-- sidebar content -->
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If i use row class for contentwrap div then the contentwrap div overflow on the left (width is 1200px vs 1170px width of the container div). If i use row-fluid class for contentwrap div then the sidebar doesn't display to the side but below the content div.

Is there something wrong with the html? Am I using bootstrap scaffolding correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to separate `row` and `span*` classes from the other classes and ids.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="contentwrap">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
          <div id="content">
             <!-- some content -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
           <div id="sidebar">
             <!-- sidebar content -->
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `margin` and `padding` are counted for the box width.